# Colon (:) meaning in Tcl script

Tags: tcl

I am new in Tcl and can't  understand  meaning  of  colon (`:`)  in  Tcl,  and I  have not  found any answer to  my  question  in  web.  Especially,  I  want  to  understand role of "`:`" in  tcl script  brought  [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10521),  for example "`$c:data`",  or  "`$c:row`".

---

…

```
  for {set y 0} {$y < $height} {incr y} \
  {
    set r:row {}
    set g:row {}
    set b:row {}
    for {set x 0} {$x < $width} {incr x} \
    {
      foreach {r g b} [$image get $x $y] break
      foreach c {r g b} { lappend $c:row [set $c] }
    }
    foreach c {r g b} { lappend $c:data [set $c:row] }
  }
```

…

```
      foreach c {r g b} \
      { 
        set c00 [lindex [set $c:data] [expr {$y - 2}] [expr {$x - 2}]]
        set c01 [lindex [set $c:data] [expr {$y - 1}] [expr {$x - 0}]]
        set c02 [lindex [set $c:data] [expr {$y - 2}] [expr {$x + 2}]]
        set c10 [lindex [set $c:data] [expr {$y + 0}] [expr {$x - 1}]]
        set c11 [lindex [set $c:data] [expr {$y + 0}] [expr {$x - 0}]]
        set c12 [lindex [set $c:data] [expr {$y + 0}] [expr {$x + 1}]]
        set c20 [lindex [set $c:data] [expr {$y + 2}] [expr {$x - 2}]]
        set c21 [lindex [set $c:data] [expr {$y + 1}] [expr {$x - 0}]]
```

…

Answer (score 4):

Colon in this context is just a symbol in the identifier of the Tcl variable. You can think of it as the underscore symbol that makes identifier more readable.

Comment: Thank  you  very  much  for  quick  answer. I thought it is not allowed  use  symbols like  colon  in  variable name.

Comment: @Art In Tcl, *every* character can be in a variable name in Tcl, and that includes the fact that you can even have a variable name that is an empty string.

Comment: However, the `$` syntax won't parse over a single colon; that's why `[set $c:data]` is necessary in the script. I think an array would've been clearer (`$data($c)`)…

Comment: I  have another  question  on  this topic.  If  colon  is  just  part of  name  of  the  variable,  why  the  result  of  above-mentioned  Tcl  script  is  changed when  i  change  names  of   variables  `"r:row", "g:row", "b:row"`,  especially in case they  are  used  only  once :  `"set r:row {}; set g:row {}; set b:row {}"`,   and  they  are  not   used  further.  Has  the  word  `"row"`  any  role  here  (it  is  used  further  in  the  script)?  Thank you  in  advance.